# Can I have multiple User Accounts in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: users

Can I have multiple user accounts in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to User Accounts under System Settings and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button placed in the left down corner.

- To do that, you may need to unlock first. See right top corner.

You can also create in terminal. (Ctrl + Alt + T)

```
sudo useradd UserNameHere
sudo passwd UserNameHere <<enter>>
```